# Show that in the disjoint cycle form of the right regular representation $T_g(x)=xg$ of $G$,each cycle has length $|g|.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $G$ be a finite group.Show that in the disjoint cycle form of the right regular representation $T_g(x)=xg$ of $G$,each cycle has length $|g|.$

Every finite group $G$ is isomorphic to a group of permutations $\overline G$.

Here the group $\overline G=\{T_g:g\in G\}$ where $T_g(x)=xg$ is a permutation of $G$.

Now if $o(g)=n$ then $(T_g)^n(x)=T_{g^n}(x)=xg^n=x=Id(x)\implies o(T_g)=n$

**PROBLEM**:

I dont understand what should I prove.Is this what am I supposed to prove?

What does it mean each cycle has length $|g|$?

Please help.

Comment: The cycles are simply the orbits ...

Comment: Note that $xg^r=x$ iff $g^r=1$ (using $1$ for the identity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical cycle will be
$$(a,ag,ag^2,\ldots,ag^{n-1})$$
where $n=|g|$.